# RST Aerial fork service - can't unscrew the bottom bolt

Tags: fork

I have a problem with the RST Aerial fork service. I try to unscrew the bottom bolt (on the mechanical lock-out system side), however, the bolt spins in both directions and it is not possible to unscrew it. Is s there a way to unscrew this screw?

So far I've done:

- I hit several times with a rubber hammer in allen key of screw
- I used WD-40 for the screw
- "fast unscrewing" - I used a drill-driver

Comment: "Rubber hummer" -- the SUV that literally bounces off obstacles.  (Typo fixed.)

Comment: It’s probably just spinning the inner rod. Have you tried compressing and keeping it there with some zip ties or alternatively using some objects to wedge it at full extension before trying the bolt. It should be normally threaded.

Comment: @WarrenBurton thanks for the answer. I haven't tried with compression. Should I do this with a full air piston or without air?

Comment: @Adrian Definitely without air. Never dismantle an air fork with air in it, that way leads to mayhem and sadness. My theory is that you need to get a bit of friction on the base of the inner rod or possibly lock it into potential lugs to unscrew the retaining bolt. This manual http://bike-manual.com/brands/fisher/om/assets/pdfs/10rst_forks_engdefi.pdf just says to "dismantle the fork" which implies it should be simple.

Comment: @WarrenBurton well, it's not so easy. After draining the air, there is no way to compress the fork :(

Comment: Looking at this answer https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43232/how-to-remove-slider-legs-from-old-rst-suspension-fork?rq=1 seems some RST forks might have an internal hex to immobilise